# Provide GIS assets to Maximo tables, but not to map

Tags: sql, oracle, gis, integration, maximo

I have a `sewer` table/layer in my GIS database that I serve up to Maximo as assets (via an ESRI feature service).

The sewers are coded as either `active` or `abandoned` in an `asset_status` field (in GIS).

**Problem:**

I want the abandoned sewers to be **included** in the assets table in Maximo (for decommissioning purposes), but I want them to be **excluded** from the Maxino map.

I want to do all this with a **single integration/feature service**.

**How can I do this?**

<sup>*(Keyword: Maximo Spatial)*</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can achieve this by **excluding the geometry** of the abandoned sewers in a **view** (but include the non-spatial portion of the records for decommissioning purposes).

```
select
    --other fields would be included in the view
    case
        when asset_status <> 'ABAN' then shape
    end as shape
from
    sewer
```

---

An alternative option might be to exclude the abandoned sewers in the feature service's [**symbology**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-a-layer-symbology-file.htm). Users wouldn't be able to see the abandoned sewers in the map, but they would still be able to select them for work orders, which isn't quite what I want.